# Debug uBoot with JTAG and Trace32?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, u-boot

I am bit new to this field and my query here is a bit vague. I am particularly interested in how any of you, who have had experience with uBoot and a JTAG debugger (like a Lauterbach), have gone about tackling and resolving an issue within uBoot.

Specifically, I would really appreciate if you could describe the *problem* encountered within uBoot, and how did the JTAG help you resolve the issue.

Thanks,
vj

Comment: I'm not quite seeing a specific question here, this sounds more like a survey.  Since u-boot is designed to be interactive and avoid the routine need for hardware debug tools, normally it's pretty amenable to investigation via debug messages.  I supposed an exception would be problems early in startup, particularly with a new port or on a board that may have hardware bugs - ie, things going wrong before you have a working serial or usb driver (or a configured network if that's your only access), or if you have to do something like inject a bitstream into an FPGA before you have off-board I/O.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this many times using Texas Instruments' CCS debugger.  I would create a dummy project with the u-boot source code and then attach.  Afterward, I can load the u-boot symbols or the u-boot app itself and step through the code.  Reloading and restarting u-boot is helpful to work through issues.

This applies to any problem with u-boot, including start-up problems.

Answer (score 0):

I use LPCXpresso (based on Eclipse) to debug U-Boot on my board (with LPC4350 MCU).

But be careful, you could have problem to debug and you maybe need to modify the .lds file (linker script). 
You have to find this file but be cautious, the file is copied and modified when you configure  the compilation for your board, you have to look for the original file.

Then if you find

```
/DISCARD/ :
{
*(*)
}
```

in the .lds file, you won't be able to debug. Just remove it or comment it.